# My 2013 Accord has no power and I cannot figure out why

Tags: honda, electrical, accord, fuse, sedan

Last night my car had no power when I got in. No interior lights, headlights, power locks, nothing. Had a friend try to jump it and there still was no sign of electricity anywhere. Today I took a colorimeter to the battery and it was showing 12.7v. I have checked all the fuses in the engine compartment, the connections from/to the battery. I have no idea.
Recently I had my starter replaced.
Any advice would of be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check the main battery cable on both ends. More than likely one end or the other has lost connection.

Comment: Thank you for your response and warm welcome! Sorry if this is an ignorant question: I know one end connects to the positive terminal of the battery, where does the other end connect?

Comment: There's more than likely two connections: one to the starter solenoid and the other end to the alternator.